# wpf- making an entire box clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a rectangle textbox in WPF and there is already a button inside the textbox which is clickable. I need to make the entire rectangle textbox clickable, so users can click anywhere in the textbox rather than just the button to interact.

Is it possible to do so?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource TinyGrayBrush}" Height="260" Width="530" Margin="10,10,10,10" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Image x:Name="imgCard" Source="{StaticResource Exception-NoImageAvailable}" Stretch="Fill" />
        <Image x:Name="hotpickEn" Source="{StaticResource HotPickEn}" Height="20" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <Image x:Name="hotpickCh" Source="{StaticResource HotPickCH}" Height="20" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gdEnglish" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25,5,25,5"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtTitle" Text="SPARKLING SUNDAY BRUNCH BUFFET" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{StaticResource SemiDarkGrayBrush}" Margin="5,0,5,6.5" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="txtDesc" Text="Pop your Sunday Morning with luxury sparkling bubble" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" Margin="5,3.5,5,6.5" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" x:Name="txtPoint" Text="138,900 GP" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" Margin="25,3.5,25,6"  />
        <Button Grid.Row="4" x:Name="btnFindOutMore" Content="FIND OUT MORE OR REDEEM" Style="{StaticResource SmallWhiteRedButton}" Margin="12,0,12,0" FontSize="20" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gdChinese" Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25,5,25,5"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtCHTitle" Text="SPARKLING SUNDAY BRUNCH BUFFET" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{StaticResource SemiDarkGrayBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,4.667,0,5.333" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="txtCHDesc" Text="Pop your Sunday Morning with luxury sparkling bubble" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,4.667,0,5.667" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" x:Name="txtCHPoint" Text="138,900 GP" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,3.5,25,6" Width="105"  />
        <Button x:Name="btnCHFindOutMore" Grid.Row="4" Content="FIND OUT MORE OR REDEEM" Style="{StaticResource SmallWhiteRedButton}" Margin="15,0,10,0"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: you want that users can click anywhere AND the button? that sounds odd to me ... or are you hiding away the buttons borders etc. so that it looks like it is part of the whole grid?

Comment: I am not hiding anything. Yes users can click anywhere INSIDE the textbox, including the button itself. The button itself is clickable but not outside of the button,i.e the remains of the textbox.

Comment: but there is no textbox, you mean users can click anywhere inside of the grid and it should occur as if they clicked the button? other questions that need to be answered: how you make the button act? code behind or binding that is not yet in this XAML?

Comment: I'll post a snapshot so u have an idea.

Comment: see edited post

Comment: Yes users can click anywhere inside grid and it should occur as if they clicked button. The button now is fired in an event handler itself.

Comment: So you utilize codebehind event handlers for this?

Comment: Yea, it's:this.btnFindOutMore.Content = KioskResource.GetContentString("Card_FindOutMore", KioskLanguage.English);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161148/discussion-between-cookie-monster-and-x39).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Code-Behind for this:

You basically subscribe to the events of the Grid too

```
gdEnglish.TouchDown += gdEnglish_TouchDown;
gdEnglish.TouchUp += gdEnglish_TouchUp;
gdEnglish.TouchLeave += gdEnglish_TouchLeave;
gdEnglish.MouseDown += gdEnglish_MouseDown;
gdEnglish.MouseUp += gdEnglish_MouseUp;
gdEnglish.MouseLeave += gdEnglish_MouseLeave;
```

add a new private variable to indicate the current state

```
private bool gdEnglish_clickflag = false;
```

and create the different event handlers

```
private void gdEnglish_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    gdEnglish_clickflag = false;
}

private void gdEnglish_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (gdEnglish_clickflag)
    {
        gdEnglish_clickflag = false;
        e.Handled = true;

            //////////
            // YOUR //
            // CODE //
            //////////
        }
    }

private void gdEnglish_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    gdEnglish_clickflag = true;
}

private void gdEnglish_TouchLeave(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    gdEnglish_clickflag = false;
}

private void gdEnglish_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (gdEnglish_clickflag)
    {
        gdEnglish_clickflag = false;
        e.Handled = true;

        //////////
        // YOUR //
        // CODE //
        //////////
    }
}

private void gdEnglish_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    gdEnglish_clickflag = true;
}
```

I still want to recommend that you research the topic MVVM with WPF

it will make things like this more clean and easy

Comment: You left noooooo